# How do I strikethrough the title like in this code? Is there a keyboard shortcut for it?

Tags: flutter, dart

The title on the 16th line is strike through. How is that done?

[image]

I am trying to follow a tutorial in a youtube video and I cannot find a way to do this or replace it with an other code.

Comment: see this=> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `label`  instead of `title`.

```dart
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  label: "home",
  icon: Icon(Icons.apps),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  showUnselectedLabels: true,
  currentIndex: 0,
  onTap: () {},
  selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.red,
  items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.report),
      label: 'Report',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
      label: 'Settings',
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That shows that `title` is deprecated or outdated in short. It will be removed from future Flutter updates. So you should not use it.

If you'll hover your mouse over the strike-through line, it will give you documentation in detail. Like using `label` in place of the `title`.